# Intellij context menu for Gradle

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle

Just got my gradle project into Intellij and when I right click on the project name, there is and option for gradle. When I click it trys to run a task libs and it errors out. What is this all about? Is this configurable?

```
/bin/gradle-1.5/bin/gradle libs

FAILURE: Could not determine which tasks to execute.

* What went wrong:
Task 'libs' not found in root project 'bin'.

* Try:
Run gradle tasks to get a list of available tasks.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 1.773 secs

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Thoughts?

Comment: I'm afraid the problem is unclear. Do you use intellij JetGradle plugin or the third-party Gradle GUI? What IJ build do you use? Could you provide a screenshot of the context menu and the item you select there?

Comment: JetGradle is the plugin that is being used

Comment: What's about other questions?

Comment: I wrote a little tutorial on using IntelliJ with Gradle: http://javamoody.blogspot.ca/2014/02/steps-to-use-gradle-with-intellij-12-to.html maybe it might help. But what you described there really doesn't look like you're using default Gradle plugin.